# Problem starting localhost server since Mac Os Catalina update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I haven't been coding for some time. I updated my Mac Os X version to Catalina (10.15.5) and upgraded my Ruby on Rails version.

It is now impossible for me to launch my local host and try and test my code. I tried several solutions explained here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75214/postgresql-not-running-on-mac but none of them worked.

Here are the steps I do:

1. `rails s`

```
/Users/maximeroberti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/bootstrap-4.2.1/lib/bootstrap/version.rb:4: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
/Users/maximeroberti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.4.1/lib/bootstrap-sass/version.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant Bootstrap::BOOTSTRAP_SHA
/Users/maximeroberti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/bootstrap-4.2.1/lib/bootstrap/version.rb:5: warning: previous definition of BOOTSTRAP_SHA was here
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.6 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.4.3-p205), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

2. Going to localhost:3000/
3. The error I am facing is the following one when trying to connect to localhost:3000/
   `could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is a Postgres problem first and a Ruby problem second. You'll need to check with `psql` and other Postgres tools before moving to Ruby. I'd suggest checking that your OS update didn't break your Postgres server, which is a common problem. Is this Homebrew managed? If so, `brew services list`.

Comment: Starting the Rails server doesn't start PG. There's no information here regarding the PG issue.

Comment: Check if psql is running on port 5432 by using `psql` from the terminal. Then post the psql error log to get it resolved.